# Solve the equation $\cos\frac{2x}{3}+\sqrt3\sin\frac{2x}{3}=\frac{8}{3+\cos{4x}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation $$\cos\dfrac{2x}{3}+\sqrt3\sin\dfrac{2x}{3}=\dfrac{8}{3+\cos{4x}}$$

Let's divide both sides of the equation by $2$ to get $$\dfrac12\cos\dfrac{2x}{3}+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin\dfrac{2x}{3}=\dfrac{4}{3+\cos{4x}}\\\iff \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{2x}{3}\right)=\dfrac{4}{3+\cos4x}$$ The RHS appears to be $\ge1$. Then isn't then the equation equivalent to $$\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{2x}{3}\right)=1$$ which gives $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+3k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Why in the authors' solution is the equation said to be equivalent to the system $$\begin{cases}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{2x}{3}\right)=1\\\cos{4x}=1\end{cases}$$ and then it's said that all of the solutions of the first equation satisfy the second. Why is the second necessary at all?

Comment: Because $\cos 4x\ne 1$ makes the RHS $> 1$ and the equality infeasible.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz, thank you! Then why isn't $\cos{4x}=1$ enough?

Comment: nice question .....+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, I would recommend you to notice that
\begin{align*}
-1 \leq \cos(4x) \leq 1 & \Longleftrightarrow 2 \leq \cos(4x) + 3 \leq 4\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} \leq \frac{1}{\cos(4x) + 3} \leq \frac{1}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 1 \leq \frac{4}{\cos(4x) + 3} \leq 2
\end{align*}

Hence the LHS equals the RHS iff one has that
\begin{align*}
1 \leq \frac{4}{\cos(4x) + 3} = \sin\left(\frac{2x}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6}\right) \leq 1
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks! What property did you use to go from $2\le \cos{4x}+3\le4$ to $\dfrac{1}{4}\le\dfrac{1}{\cos{4x}+3}\le\dfrac12$?

Comment: @yinivem462 I divided both sides by $\cos(4x) + 3$, which is possible because it is always positive.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Doesn't the LHS become $\dfrac{2}{\cos{4x}+3}$, if so?

Comment: @yinivem462 I just inverted the fractions and multiplied by $4$.

Comment: "*I divided both sides by $\cos(4x)+3$*", I think you mean taking the reciprocal and flipping the inequality sign since the inequality is positive.

Comment: @CroCo Yes, indeed :-)